# button onClick does not map to controller method

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using a HTML form with a button which is mapped to a method in controller.
It just mapped correctly but when i run it, it gives HTML 404 - page undefined error.

Please let me know what would be the correct way to call this method from a JSP Page to invoke this method?

My controller method below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addVendor", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addVendor(@ModelAttribute("vendor") Vendor vendor,
            BindingResult result) {


        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("vendorList");
        model.addObject("vendorList", vendorList);
        model.addObject("vendor", new Vendor());

        return model;
    }
```

And my HTML Snippet which calls the above method

```
<form:form method="post" action="/firstSpring/saveVendor.html" modelAttribute="vendor">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="vendorId">VendorId:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="vendorId" value=""/></td>             
                <td><input type="button" value="add" name="addVendor" onClick="location.href=addVendor.html" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="save" /></td>
            </tr>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add single quote before addVendor.html, i.e. `"onClick="location.href='addVendor.html'" />`